# How to check if there is a space between two characters?

Tags: java, string, swing, char, jtextfield

I'm new to Java programming and I'm now developing a simple application.
Now I'm focused on finding a solution on this problem: checking if a String contained in a JTextField contains spaces between each of its characters, like: "1 + 2 - 3 + 7" (which has spaces between every char), but I can't find a solution atm.
Could you help me?
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I found an easier solution: instead of adding a space after every char, I thought I could add a space before and after every symbol using: theString.replace("symbol", " symbol ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from making a Method i would suggest using a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): ^(\d + )*\d$

This Regex allows easy modifications, to further restrict or allow certain combinations - Easily allowing numbers instead of digits. You might want to use a compiled and final Pattern in an utility class:

```
public static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile("^(\\d \\+ )*\\d$");
```

Testcase:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// [...] 

public static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile("^(\\d [\\+\\-] )*\\d$");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] testCases = {
        "1+2", "2 + 3", "5 + 6 - 4", "1 + ", "6 6"
    };
    
    for(String s:testCases) {
        final Matcher m = P.matcher(s);
        if(m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("String valid: " + s);
        } else {
            System.out.println("String invalid: " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Given output:

> String invalid: 1+2
>
> String valid: 2 + 3
>
> String valid: 5 + 6 - 4
>
> String invalid: 1 +
>
> String invalid: 6 6

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to do so by using even indices:

```
public boolean followsFormat(String string) {

    String testString = "";

    for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i += 2) {
        testString += string.trim().substring(i, i + 1);
    }

    testString = testString.trim();
    return testString.equals("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The really simple solution would just to write a for loop that gets every even index and checks if its a char.

```
public boolean hasRightSpacing(String str) {
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i+= 2) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

obviously you would have to do a little more work if all the numbers aren't a single digit.

Comment: Yep, numbers are not only a single digit, they could be up to 10 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get the string from the text field you could go

```
String str = textField.getText();
```

Then you could see if it has a space in it by going.

```
boolean containSpace = false;
if(str.contains(" "))
{
    containSpace = true;
}
```

If you want to count how many spaces I suppose you could use a for loop and chars.

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= str.length; i++)
{
    if(str.charAt(i) == ' ')
    {    
        counter++;
    }
}
```